# how to keep specific element of array always in the middle? php

Tags: php, arrays

I've following php that generates the array of languages:

```
<?php
/**
 * Language chooser for qtranslate-x plugin
 *
 * @package
 */

function get_language_list() {

    if ( function_exists( 'qtranxf_getSortedLanguages' ) ) {

        global $q_config;

        $list = array();
        foreach ( qtranxf_getSortedLanguages() as $key => $language ) {
            $list[] = array(
                'url' => qtranxf_convertURL( '', $language, false, true),
                'lan' => $q_config['language_name'][ $language ],
                'cur' => $language == $q_config['language'] ? 'current' : '',
            );
        }



        return $list;
    }

}
```

Its great, but I need to rewrite this array in a way that element which has `'cur' == 'current'` is always in the middle e.g. key is 1.

array has 3 elements. dump looks like this:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(24) ".dev/en/"
    ["lan"]=>
    string(7) "English"
    ["cur"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(24) ".dev/ka/"
    ["lan"]=>
    string(21) "ქართული"
    ["cur"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(24) ".dev/ru/"
    ["lan"]=>
    string(14) "Русский"
    ["cur"]=>
    string(7) "current"
  }
}
```

note, issue is that this order comes at random, and only rule is that current one should always be in the middle.

Comment: Why do you need `cur` to be the middle? Can't you just access it as `$list["cur"]`?

Comment: if your array is not gonna be big and you don't mind the overhead, you can store the index of the current language and at the same time also store the reference to the "middle" element and after the loop just swap those two elements

Comment: @JonathanWheeler isn't why an ephemeral question? :)

Comment: @flynorc that's an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested by @flynorc

```
/**
 * Language chooser for qtranslate-x plugin
 *
 * @package marcopolo
 */

function get_language_list() {

    if ( function_exists( 'qtranxf_getSortedLanguages' ) ) {

        global $q_config;

        $list = array();
        foreach ( qtranxf_getSortedLanguages() as $key => $language ) {
            if ( $language == $q_config['language'] ) {
                $cur = true;
                $cur_key = $key;
            } else {
                $cur = false;
            }
            $list[ $key ] = array(
                'url' => qtranxf_convertURL( '', $language, false, true),
                'lan' => $q_config['language_name'][ $language ],
                'cur' => $cur,
            );
        }

        $middle = $list[1];
        $list[1] = $list[ $cur_key ];
        $list[ $cur_key ] = $middle;

        return $list;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say :

1) search the current and remove it from the array

2) then re-insert it in the middle of the array

```
$current = array_splice($list, 
    array_search('current', array_column($list, 'cur')), 1);
array_splice($list, round(count($list)/2), 0, $current);
```